# What is the difference between simple assignments with "initial" block and without it?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

**For Example, what is the difference between these two implementations?**

*with `initial` statment:*

```
module with_initial();
reg clk,reset,enable,data;

initial begin
  clk=0;
  reset=0;
  enable=0;
  data=0;
end

always @(…)
..
end

endmodule
```

*and here without using an `initial` statement:*

```
module without_initial();
reg clk,reset,enable,data;

clk=0;
reset=0;
enable=0;
data=0;

always @(…)
..
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `without_initial` is not legal syntax, and it should produce compile errors for you, as it does for the simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5XKv).

Procedural assignments must be inside an `initial` or `always` block.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.4 *Procedural assignments*.

Also, a `reg` can be declared with an initial value outside of an `initial` block:

```
module without_initial;

reg clk=0;
reg reset=0;
reg enable=0;
reg data=0;

endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.8 *Variable declarations*.

Answer (score 0):

Initial block is where your execution starts and they execute  at 
time 0. This is a non synthesiable procedural statement ( in the sense it cannot be modelled to hardware) . It is just used for initializing all the variable and drives them with specific values.

In veriog (HDL) it's however mandatory to have atleast one initial block . Maybe if you skip adding that block the error caused would be due to following reasons  :

1) The compiler never knowing what to drive into the modelled gates used in your code .
2)  The assignment to the variables never happen.

Not so damn sure about it. But this is what I feel happens behind the scenario.